# c# Garbage Collection. .NET CLR Memory Perfmon counters showing 0 for gen 0 heap size etc. What does this mean?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have been reading about the .NET CLR Memory Performance counters

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc(v=vs.110).aspx

Lots of counters have the following caveat:

```
This counter is updated at the end of a garbage collection, not at each allocation.
```

I have spotted a memory leak for an app, and checked out the gen 0 heap size, gen 1, # bytes on all heaps and they are displaying as 0. Can this trusted? How can I distinguish between the below two scenarios?

1. A garbage collection has  not taken place yet
2. My app does not have any gen 0,1 etc allocations
   ?

Comment: The GC not running at all is indeed a good reason why you'd have a memory leak.  Hard to write code like that, you'd have to allocate a lot of unmanaged memory like bitmaps or COM objects.  Throw in a GC.Collect() call and have a look-see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put my money on 1) A garbage collection has not taken place yet.

I've compared the performance monitor output of the following two scenarios:

```
static void Main(string args[])
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In this case, the performance monitor shows 0 bytes in all heaps.

with this which shows 22,496 bytes in all heaps.

```
static void Main(string args[])
{
    GC.Collect();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This would suggest that even an empty app in which no memory is directly allocated has some heap allocations.

You could test this out by placing a call to `GC.Collect` somewhere in your code.